# AutoHotkey error when using hotstrings in imported secondary script

Tags: autohotkey

In this AutoHotkey script (version 1.1.36.02) when pressing the key combination Ctrl+Shift+Win+s the main file 'mainMenu.ahk' imports the content of the secondary file 'subMenu.ahk' and opens a context menu where the mouse pointer is located.

The script works correctly but if I try to declare a hotstring in the imported file 'subMenu.ahk' then when I run the script I get the error "Error: Menu does not exist".

To reproduce the error simply uncomment line 3 of the file 'subMenu.ahk':
:*:->::➜

##### ◾ Pop-up menu:

[image: Pop-up menu]

##### ◾ Code of main script 'mainMenu.ahk':

[image: Code of main script 'mainMenu.ahk']

##### ◾ Code of the imported file 'subMenu.ahk':

[image: Code of the imported file 'subMenu.ahk']

##### ◾ Error that appears when the code (  :*:->::➜  ) is uncommented:

[image: Error that appears]

##### ◾ Github repo of the project:

[git repo](https://github.com/JoseCarlosGZ/AHK_error_menu_hotstring/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)

Comment: No Error here if I uncomment  `:*:->::➜` and reload the script.

Comment: @Relax 
Which version of AutoHotkey do you have installed?

If you unzip the hotstring ( :*:->::➜ ) and reload the script, don't you get an error?

Comment: [Latest AHK v1:](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe) 1.1.37.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not loading all content of mainMenu.ahk.

```
---- C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\AHK_error_menu_hotstring-main\mainMenu.ahk
002: SendMode,Input
003: SetWorkingDir,%A_ScriptDir%
---- c:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\AHK_error_menu_hotstring-main\assets\subMenu.ahk
003: Return (2.86)
```

Try including your subMenu.ahk after the creation of the menus, like this:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%

; #Include assets\subMenu.ahk ;It Imports the subMenu.ahk file

weekdaysVariable = 
(
 1. Monday
 2. Tuesday
 3. Wednesday
 4. Thursday
 5. Friday
)

arraySubmenu := {"01. Weekdays":weekdaysVariable, "02. myFunction() located in subMenu.ahk":"", "Option03":"value03", "Option04":"value04", "Option05":"value05", "Option06":"value06", "Option07":"value07 Brk", "Option08":"value08", "Option09":"value09", "Option10":"value10", "Option11":"value11", "Option12":"value12", "Option13":"value13 Brk", "Option14":"value14", "Option15":"value15", "Option16":"value16", "Option17":"value17","Option18":"value18"}

TopMenu := { arraySubmenu: "subMenu"}
TopMenu("MainMenu",TopMenu*)

#Include assets\subMenu.ahk ; After the main menu creation

Return
```